# How to Deploy Mule as a REST Service

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-cluster, mule-component

Hi I am working with Mule Studio and i am successfully running my flow in Mule Studio. I have certain issues related to implementation level since i have multiple flows in the one project.

1. How to deploy Mule as a REST Service with the existing flow.
2. If i am deploying my Mule as a REST Service what are the inputs i have to provide to make it run from the external HTTP Client based program.
3. When to use HTTP Client and when to use Mule Client. Which one fits where.

Comment: So you need to add a rest endpoint into a existing flow ?

Comment: nopes i know how to add REST endpoint but i want to deploy it as a stand alone service , While i am running it from Mule Studio its running , i want to create a Spring REST Service with standalone Mule Server runtime , based on that i am interested to know more about the points which i have mention in the questions.

Comment: When you say "stand alone service", do you mean as a Mule application running in the Mule Standalone container?

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of RAML

1.create a RAML and generate the flows which internally referes your current flows

2. you can configure the Http details in generated flows
3. why you want to use http client and Mule client in your flows?